# How to apply lag function on streaming dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, spark-structured-streaming

I have a streaming dataframe having three columns time,col1,col2. I have to apply lag function on column2. I have tried following query.

```
val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.oderBy("time")
df.select(col("time"),col("col1"),lag("col3",1).over(w))
```

But It gives following exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `lag()` is just not supported for streams: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/9f30d9280308f8f33f7459e39f2683e8fea49026/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala#L276 But you can use `lag()` on non-streaming dataframes.

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Comment: @SergeyKovalev - is there an alternative for `lag()` in Pyspark? or an alternative way of doing sessioning?